# Scrollview XML layout issue

Tags: java, android, xml

Hoping this is a simple one.

I have a layout that uses a scrollview. This was fine until I wanted to put an image and textview above it then have the scrollview with my edittexts below it.

At the moment I'm getting the following errors:

```
01-22 20:13:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 20:13:32.228: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flybase2/com.example.flybase2.addAppointment}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #26: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

I have tried to change the scroll views width attribute (which i believe that error is pointing too) with no luck.

Here's my XML. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLink"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/viewcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Appointments"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</LinearLayout>

\\ERROR: On width attribute
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAppName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment Type:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment Time:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment Time:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comments:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAppCom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Appointment Date Alarm:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
    android:textOff="Alarm Off"
    android:textOn="Alarm On" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Appointment"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddAppointment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add" />

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set one child layout to a ScrollView. I don't know why it's showing you that you didn't set `android:layout_width` attribute, but your problem is definitely that you have multiple child views in your ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLink"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/viewcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Appointments"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAppName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment Type:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment Time:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointment Time:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comments:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputAppCom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Appointment Date Alarm:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ToggleButton"
    android:textOff="Alarm Off"
    android:textOn="Alarm On" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Appointment"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddAppointment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Ahmed Thanks for your reply. I have added the linearlayout and my image and textview show, but now everything within the linear layout does not show.

Comment: Did you set the orientation to vertical? Does the scrolling work?

Comment: @Ahmed Yes the linear layout is in a vertical orientation. I have added a picture showing what it looks like now. The scrollview is completely blank.

Comment: You did not set the orientation of your parent LinearLayout. Set it to vertical and it should work

Comment: @user1352057 set your main layout to vertical as well. it should help.

Comment: Thank you guys! It was indeed my main parent layout that was the issue.